# Geo Heat Pump Leak

Tags: hvac, heat-pump

First: water source heat pump on a well.

I’ve got a leak at the (I think) inlet before the compressor. It’s just before the ball valve. See pic with blue towel. I can make the fix but I’m worried about getting air in my loop. Does anyone have ideas for how to burp air out of the system? Perhaps the drain on the outlet side? See pic.

[image]